# perl threads create - how to correctly specify class instance method?

Tags: multithreading, perl

Having problems with threads.  Keep getting error when creating a thread using a class instance method as the subroutine.  The method and params variables are set based on other stuff, so I have to call the class instance method this way.  Without the threads, it works just fine.  Can't figure out the correct way to specify it for threads create:

```
my $instance = someclass->new();
my $method = 'get';
my $params = { 'abc' => 123 };
my $thread = threads->create($instance->$method,$params);
```

This gives me the error "Not a CODE reference".  I think this may be actually calling the method, and using the return as the argument.  Okay, tried this:

```
my $thread = threads->create(\&{$instance->$method},$params);
```

This gives me the error "Not a subroutine reference".  I would appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
my $thread = threads->create(sub { $instance->$method(@_) }, $params);
```

Or, you could just pass the instance and the method to the first argument as well:

```
package SomeClass;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    bless { args => [ @_ ] };
}

sub get {
    my $self = shift;
    my $args = shift;
    return join(" ", @{ $self->{args} }, $args->{abc});
}

package main;

use 5.012;
use threads;

my $x = SomeClass->new("An instance");

threads->create(sub { say $x->get(@_) }, {'abc' => 123 })->join;

threads->create(
    sub {
        my $instance = shift;
        my $method = shift;
        say $instance->$method(@_);
    }, $x, 'get', { 'abc' => 123 }
)->join;
```

In fact, I would prefer the latter, to avoid closing on `$instance`.

Comment: Thanks.  I used your second method.  I prefer not to use variables outside my function scope (anonymous sub in this case).  Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Calling a method without parens is the same thing as calling the method without arguments:

```
$foo->bar eq $foo->bar()
```

To create a coderef, you can either specify a lambda that wraps the method call, e.g.

```
threads->create(sub{ $instance->get($params) })
```

(see Sinan Ünürs answer), or you can use the universal `can` function.

The `can` method resolves a method in the same way a method would be resolved if it were called, and returns the coderef for that method if it was found, or returns `undef`. This makes it usable as a boolean test.

Do note that methods are just subroutines with the first argument being the invocant (the object):

```
my $code = $instance->can($method) or die "Can't resolve $method";
threads->create($code, $instance, $params);
```

However, `can` may fail for poorly written classes that make use of `AUTOLOAD`.